# Handler not updating UI

Tags: java, android, android-handler

First of all, Im new to android. So i was displaying the current time on a **TextView** in the MainActivity.java using a **Handler**, which worked just fine. Then i used a TimePicker(which is actually in another activity, TimeActivity.java) to pick a time, at which the time stops.

*For example, if the time picked using the TimePicker is 8:30, the time in TextView will cease to advance further beyond 8:30*

Also theres a STOP button with which calls **handler.removeMessages(0);** to stop the handler and hence the time.

- The problem is, when i come back from TimeActivity.java, the **TextView** is blank which looks like the *handler* is not running but it successfully Toasts "Time Stopped" when the time's hit. Whats this anomaly?
- I happen to face another problem, The Toast, "Time stopped" in *stopTime()* prevails on the screen for an abnormally longer period of time but it's normal with the Toast in *stop(View v)* even though i used the same logic to stop the handler in both methods. What's causing this?

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
import static com.gamecodeschool.broadcast.TimeActivity.minute1;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button start,stop,set;
TextView textView;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Views
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    set = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void stop(View v) {
    handler.removeMessages(0);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void runInBackground(View v) {
    handler.post(r);
    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //String time = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
            textView.setText(stringBuilder);
            if (minute==minute1){
                stopTime();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,100);
        }
    };
}

private void stopTime() {
    handler.removeMessages(0);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Time Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }
```

And Here's my TimeActivity

```
public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TimePicker timePicker;
Button button;
TextView textView;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
static int hour1,minute1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);

    timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeView);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    showTime(hour,minute);
}

private void showTime(int hour, int minute) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
    textView.setText(stringBuilder);
}

public void saveTime(View v){
    hour1 = timePicker.getHour();
    minute1 = timePicker.getMinute();
    showTime(hour1,minute1);
    Toast.makeText(TimeActivity.this,hour1+":"+minute1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating UI must be done on the UIThread, for instance to update your `TextView`you should for example :

```
public void runInBackground(View v) {
    handler.post(r);
    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //String time = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    textView.setText(stringBuilder);
                }
            });
            textView.setText(stringBuilder);
            if (minute==minute1){
                stopTime();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,100);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: No its not working. The same problem persists. Any other fixes? Thanks for the help though.